# need erc20 transactions value in USD, not in ethereum

Tags: etherscan

I have tested and implemented a script which is fetching data of token address from etherscan but the issue is values are in eth but i want in usd, is there any way to get values of erc20 transaction in US dollar's.
Any external apis will also work..

Comment: If it works for any ERC20 token, you could just fetch the USDC price in ETH for the same timestamp and use it to calculate your token's price in USDC.

Comment: But it might be good to use several USD-pegged tokens in case one of them depegs.